# Where can I find custom dictionaries for my Kobo Glo?

Tags: customization, kobo, kobo-glo, dictionaries

I'd like to load some custom dictionaries on my Kobo Glo, since the preloaded ones sometimes lack many words.

The monolingual ones seems to be fairly complete, but I find the ones used for translation to be far from comprehensive.

I know that there is a tool called [Penelope](http://www.albertopettarin.it/penelope.html), aimed at converting between various dictionary formats, but the job seems especially tricky for Kobo ones, since it requires many dependencies.

If someone has successfully used it to create Kobo-compatible dictionaries, can please point out if there is some place where they can be downloaded?

Comment: is this what you are looking for? http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=196931

Comment: No, these are the direct links to the standard Kobo dictionaries, if one prefer to get them that way instead of directly downloading them on the device via wi-fi.

Comment: You can find a few custom dictionaries [here](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=196925).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apologies for replying as an answer, I have no sufficient reputation to comment.

I am the creator of Penelope. I thought about this for a bit, but the main problem is that I am continuously asked to "convert" materials that are clearly pirated from copyrighted, commercial dictionaries --- which I always refuse --- and hosting them onto a public web site would yield to legal issues.

Probably the best option would be creating a thread in MobileRead, but clearly only for public domain or CC-licensed materials.

EDIT: I created such thread: http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?p=2755188

EDIT 2: I posted directions on how to install custom dictionaries on Kobo devices in the Penelope GitHub README: https://github.com/pettarin/penelope